# MultiPoint to FeatureCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to turn a MultiPoint geometry to a feature collection with each point as its own feature. How come the following code will not do that?

```
var points = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(
    [[1.3634359574461996, 31.636034304440155],
     [3.6046468949461996, 31.148372138748694],
     [-0.9656656050538004, 29.172742327143503],
     [2.8575765824461996, 29.172742327143503],
     [0.7042562699461996, 30.506858885801098],
     [-1.6248452925538004, 30.884738935660458],
     [-3.8221109175538004, 27.62655429384725],
     [2.2862875199461996, 25.781544169671214]]);

// var mp = ee.FeatureCollection(points)
// print(mp)
var mp = ee.FeatureCollection(points.map(function(p){
  var point = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(p), {})
  return point
}))
print(mp)
```

This code returns the following error message: "`points.map is not a function`"

EDITS:
The following code will not work either:

```
var points = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(
    [[1.3634359574461996, 31.636034304440155],
     [3.6046468949461996, 31.148372138748694],
     [-0.9656656050538004, 29.172742327143503],
     [2.8575765824461996, 29.172742327143503],
     [0.7042562699461996, 30.506858885801098],
     [-1.6248452925538004, 30.884738935660458],
     [-3.8221109175538004, 27.62655429384725],
     [2.2862875199461996, 25.781544169671214]]);

var pointses = points.geometries()
print(pointses)
var mp2 = ee.FeatureCollection(pointses)
print(mp2)
```

and returns this error:
"`Collection: Geometries cannot have their properties modified or be placed into collections.`"

which leads me to believe that a FeatureCollection cannot be created from a set of points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `points` to be a list, rather than a MultiPoint Geometry. There is no map function for MultiPoint Geometries, but there is one for lists:

```
var points = /* color: #d63000 */ee.List(
    [[1.3634359574461996, 31.636034304440155],
     [3.6046468949461996, 31.148372138748694],
     [-0.9656656050538004, 29.172742327143503],
     [2.8575765824461996, 29.172742327143503],
     [0.7042562699461996, 30.506858885801098],
     [-1.6248452925538004, 30.884738935660458],
     [-3.8221109175538004, 27.62655429384725],
     [2.2862875199461996, 25.781544169671214]]);

// var mp = ee.FeatureCollection(points)
// print(mp)
var mp = ee.FeatureCollection(points.map(function(p){
  var point = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(p), {})
  return point
}))
print(mp)
```

A suggested edit to this question also points out that you may use the `.coordinates()` method to cast your coordinates to a mappable form:

```
var points = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(
    [[1.3634359574461996, 31.636034304440155],
     [3.6046468949461996, 31.148372138748694],
     [-0.9656656050538004, 29.172742327143503],
     [2.8575765824461996, 29.172742327143503],
     [0.7042562699461996, 30.506858885801098],
     [-1.6248452925538004, 30.884738935660458],
     [-3.8221109175538004, 27.62655429384725],
     [2.2862875199461996, 25.781544169671214]]);

// var mp = ee.FeatureCollection(points)
// print(mp)
var mp = ee.FeatureCollection(points.coordinates().map(function(p){
  var point = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(p), {})
  return point
}))
print(mp)
```

Comment: Is there a way of not having to do this "by hand"?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean "by hand." It seems pretty automated to me...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Because of the nature of my project, I'm drawing and re-drawing the points on the map based on further analysis (there are many points). So I would like to avoid to have to copy the code and change to ee.List. By automated I mean that directly takes the MultiPoint and convert to a List.

Comment: You might take a look at https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-geometry-multipoint-coordinates and other functions for Multipoint...I'm pretty sure you should be able to get your Multipoint converted to a List using a couple functions. Open a new question on this site if you can't solve it!